# Bash not appending array to new index. Just extends first index

Tags: bash, array, bash-functions

I am using arrays in bash and one particular array is behaving unusually.

I am using a function and calling an external script which returns a value to be appended to an array as follows:

```
function get_unit_coverage() {

 for sub_unit in "$@"
 do
     extracted_value=$( ./external_script.sh $file $sub_unit )
     my_array+=$extracted_value
 done
}
```

I pass this function an array and expect the array to be appended each iteration.

However the retun of:

```
echo "${my_Array[0]}"
```

is

```
52.5500%66.6400%16.4300%47.8800%40.6600%45.6800%43.3400%74.5100%87.4600%45.6300%65.6100%58.0900%%47.5800%5.9500%7.6500%1.8000%
```

The external_script.sh simply echoes these values, is this a potential issue?

Comment: Take care on the capitalization also (array vs Array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To append new elements to an array:

```
array+=( new elements here )
```

In your case:

```
my_array+=( "$extracted_value" )
```

When you do

```
array+=$variable
```

you are appending to the first element of the array.  It is the same as

```
array[0]+=$variable
```

---

Also note  that in

```
extracted_value=$( ./external_script.sh $file $sub_unit )
```

the values `$file` and  `$sub_unit` will be split on whitespace and undergo filename globbing.  To prevent this, use `"$file"` and `"$sub_unit"` instead (i.e. double-quote the variable expansions).

Likewise, saying

```
my_array+=( $extracted_value )
```

would split the value of `$extracted_value` into multiple words, and each word would undergo filename globbing to generate new element in the array.  That would be better written (as already mentioned),

```
my_array+=( "$extracted_value" )
```

This is general advice and there's no reason to *not* do this regardless of whether you *know* your values are already single words containing no globbing characters.

Comment: Is there a formal term for why I was implicitly only appending to the first index?  In Python this would work fine, I don't see why the right hand side would make all the difference when the left hand side and operator is constant.

Comment: @cc6g11 What you want to use is called a _compound assignment_ in the `bash` manual. That's the name of `variable=( ... )` and `variable+=( ... )` and is specifically for assigning to or adding to an array. Both `variable="..."` and `variable+="..."` are ordinary variable assignments.  When an array name is used as just `arrayname` in an ordinary assignment, you modify its first element.  The same goes for using it like `echo "$arrayname"` instead of `echo "${arrayname[@]}"` (i.e. only the first element is printed).

Answer (score 0):

You added to a string and read it as an array (as Kusalananda explained well above). But your question shows how a variable can be treated as an array. In fact a simple variable can easily become an array.

```
$ a+=1
$ a+=2
$ echo "$a"
12
$ echo "${a[0]}"
12
$ a+=(3)
$ echo "$a"
12
$ echo "${a[0]}"
12
$ echo "${a[1]}"
3
```